# how can i store a return data from an event handler with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I return data from an event handler to use it in another place
like if I use react I will store it in redux then can I use it but I wanna do it in pure JavaScript
I try to solve the problem with local storage but I have another problem the data its returned just when I refresh the page

category.js

```
let sectioncategory = document.getElementById("section-category");


///////////////////////////////////////// DRAW SECTION CATEGORY ////////////////////////////////
let drawCategoryItems =()=>{
    let categoryitems = datacategory.map((item)=>{
        if(item.name == "all"){
            return `<div class="category-item category-item-active px-2 mb-2" id="category-item-${item.id}"  onclick="Handlecategoryclick(${item.id} )"> 
                        <h6 class="mb-0">${item.name}</h6>     
                    </div>`
        }else{

        return `<div class="category-item  px-2 mb-2" id="category-item-${item.id}"  onclick="Handlecategoryclick(${item.id})"> 
                    <h6 class="mb-0">${item.name}</h6>
                    <div class="item-icon"><div class="icon"><img src="images/slider and icons/${item.img}" alt="footbal-icon" class="img-fluid "></div></div>
                </div>`
            }
    }).join('');

    sectioncategory.innerHTML = categoryitems;

}

drawCategoryItems();
/////////////////////////////////////////  END  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//WHEN I CLICK ON ONE OF CATEGORY ITEM LIKE ACTION ADVENTURE ARCADE..........
let  Handlecategoryclick = ( id )=>{
     //active category item
     let allofCategoryItems = document.querySelectorAll(".category-item");

     allofCategoryItems.forEach((item)=>{
        item.classList.remove('category-item-active');
     });

     allofCategoryItems.forEach((item)=>{
        if (item.getAttribute("id") === `category-item-${id}` ) {
            
            item.classList.toggle("category-item-active")
        }

     })
     // end active category item

     //get name like action or arcade from datacategory
        let itemName =  datacategory.filter((item)=>{
                return item.id === id
            }).map((item)=>{
                return item.name ;
            })
    //get name like action or arcade from datacategory
            console.log(itemName[0]);
    // function that return the new feltring array based on name of category
    let nameOfcategory = ()=>{
        let newdata = [];
            if(itemName[0] === "all"){
                newdata = data ;
            }else{
        
                newdata =  data.filter((item)=>{
                    return item.category === itemName[0];
                })
        }

        return newdata ; 
    }

     let nameOfCategory = nameOfcategory(); // i wanna return this data 
    
}
//WHEN I CLICK ON ONE OF CATEGORY ITEM LIKE ACTION ADVENTURE ARCADE..........
```

script.js

```
let data = //i wanna set the data here
```

Comment: Declare a variable outside of the handler and then do `data = value`

Comment: i try it before but its doesn't work

Comment: You have a lot of options the question is how big this project is and which one is right for you... First option would be session storage.... You can also create your own server and store the data in that server...